# Couldn't resolve host '1511623453.cloud.vimeo.com'

Tags: php, vimeo, vimeo-api

Alright... I've chased the trail around the internet for this one, and I'm coming up with nothing.

Trying to use the PHP Vimeo API to upload videos. I have upload permission on my app, I've got tokens, and client id and secret stuff all set up, and a small myriad of other things that I've put together to make everything work... and... now I'm getting this and I have no idea what to do with it :P

```
 PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Vimeo\Exceptions\VimeoRequestException' with message 'Unable to complete request.[Couldn't resolve host '1511623453.cloud.vimeo.com']' in /home/theo/software-dev/classes/vimeo/src/Vimeo/Vimeo.php:154 Stack trace:
#0 /home/theo/software-dev/classes/vimeo/src/Vimeo/Vimeo.php(396): Vimeo\Vimeo->_request('https://1511623...', Array)
#1 /home/theo/software-dev/classes/vimeo/src/Vimeo/Vimeo.php(320): Vimeo\Vimeo->perform_upload('users/test/outp...', Array)
#2 /home/theo/software-dev/vim_test.php(20): Vimeo\Vimeo->upload('users/test/outp...', false)
#3 {main}   thrown in /home/theo/software-dev/classes/vimeo/src/Vimeo/Vimeo.php on line 154
```

The upload script is super simple, and I doubt to be the source of the error, though here it is:

```
  1 <?php
  2 include("./config/vim.php");
  3 require("./classes/vimeo/autoload.php");
  4 
  5 $lib = new \Vimeo\Vimeo($client_id, $client_secret);
  6 
  7 $lib->setToken($token);
  8 
  9 $response = $lib->upload('users/test/output.mp4', false);
```

Any suggestions or thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: the error means php cannot connect to the server, I've pinged it and it seems to be offline. Where did you get that hostname ?

Comment: Pinged it too and its down.

Comment: @PedroLobito I can visit the url with no problem. I get output saying "not found" and it throws a 404 error, but that is still a response from a server.

Comment: The api may have some outdated urls. Make sure you've the latest version, https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.php

Comment: Any chance that something is confusing an IP address with a host name or vice-versa?  `1511623453` would be IP address `29.139.25.90`.  Is that IP familiar?

Comment: latest version update did it. Docs are out of date, and said that 1.1.0 was the latest version, so that's what I was running with. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Try and close all the browers on the computer or phone then make sure your api has the lastet version.